# Bootstrap close one div resize another

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3 as the framework for my website.

With this code I am displaying 2 elements (**div A** and **div B**) on a page, each with 50% width of the screen size.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6" id="A"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6" id="B"></div>
</div>
```

I want to **close div B** and **resize div A to 100%** width of the screen by clicking a button/element.
How could one do that with Bootstrap? Is there a CSS or JavaScript way built in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you're not ending your DIVs properly. Instead of `</div` you should use `</div>`. Then, you can do what you're asking with some jQuery, supposing the button which will be clicked has a `button` id:

```
$("#button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#B").hide();
    $("#A").removeClass("col-lg-6").addClass("col-lg-12");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/juu60dbu/

Or, if you want to do it with pure JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("B").style.display = "none";

    document.getElementById("A").className = "";
    document.getElementById("A").className = "col-lg-12";
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g8k55deg/

Comment: I updated my question with inverted DIVs, as the OP requested, and also added a pure JS method.